# Is it possible to write "local" script / hook for maven + jenkins packaging process?

Tags: java, maven, build, jenkins, hook

I'm using jenkins to build package. My package uses jankins environment variable BUILD_ID, which provides build date: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

Problem is, that i need to use that date in xml configuration file, in element of type dateTime from schema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.

Jenkins uses format

```
YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss
```

for BUILD_ID var, and dateTime field needs format

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
```

('T' instead of '_' between date and time, and ':' instead of '-' as time separator).

I know there is plugin for jenkins that allows to set custom date format for BUILD_ID variable, but i cant touch jenkins. Is it possible to write an "local" script / hook (by local i mean in the scope of my project, without any changes to external tools) that will convert that BUILD_ID after it read it from jenkins ? Right now i read BUILD_ID with that line in pom's  element:

```
<buildinfo.timestamp>${env.BUILD_ID}</buildinfo.timestamp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tiny maven plugin called [maven-timestamp-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-timestamp-plugin/) that might help you. It creates a timestamp in the format you like and writes it into a system property which you can access similar to the Jenkins `BUILD_ID`.

Your plugin configuration would look something like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.keyboardsamurais.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-timestamp-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <propertyName>timestamp</propertyName>
    <timestampPattern>yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss</timestampPattern>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
     <goals>
      <goal>create</goal>
     </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

... and in your XML file you can write `<buildinfo.timestamp>${timestamp}</buildinfo.timestamp>`

Comment: Still, this one needs to install maven plugin on machine with jankins, right ? I have no permissions to do that, but i will ask our admin if its possible. Vote up but i will hold on with accepting, maybe there will be someone with solution :)

Comment: The maven-timestamp-plugin is available on Maven Central. So if your build server (i.e. there machine on which Jenkins is running) has access to it, there shouldn't be any problem using this plugin.